# How to convert XML data into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

```
<OrderContact>
    <Contact>
        <ContactName>Harj Dhamrait</ContactName>
        <ContactDescription>13</ContactDescription>
        <ListOfContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue />454854 5532281</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>TelephoneNumber</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
            </ContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue>0987262 532281</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>Other</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
                <ContactNumberTypeCodedOther>Switchboard</ContactNumberTypeCodedOther>
            </ContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue>abc@gmail.com</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>EmailAddress</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
            </ContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue>01322 296 252</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>FaxNumber</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
            </ContactNumber>
        </ListOfContactNumber>
    </Contact>
</OrderContact>
```

I need to convert this to a SQL Server table:

| TelephoneNumber | Switchboard | EmailAddress | FaxNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 454854 5532281 | 0987262 532281 | abc@gmail.com | 01322 296 252 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Data XML = '<OrderContact>
    <Contact>
        <ContactName>Harj Dhamrait</ContactName>
        <ContactDescription>13</ContactDescription>
        <ListOfContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue>454854 5532281</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>TelephoneNumber</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
            </ContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue>0987262 532281</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>Other</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
                <ContactNumberTypeCodedOther>Switchboard</ContactNumberTypeCodedOther>
            </ContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue>abc@gmail.com</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>EmailAddress</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
            </ContactNumber>
            <ContactNumber>
                <ContactNumberValue>01322 296 252</ContactNumberValue>
                <ContactNumberTypeCoded>FaxNumber</ContactNumberTypeCoded>
            </ContactNumber>
        </ListOfContactNumber>
    </Contact>
</OrderContact>'

SELECT
    TelephoneNumber = xc.value('(ContactNumber[ContactNumberTypeCoded="TelephoneNumber"]/ContactNumberValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Switchboard = xc.value('(ContactNumber[ContactNumberTypeCodedOther="Switchboard"]/ContactNumberValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    EmailAddress = xc.value('(ContactNumber[ContactNumberTypeCoded="EmailAddress"]/ContactNumberValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    FaxNumber = xc.value('(ContactNumber[ContactNumberTypeCoded="FaxNumber"]/ContactNumberValue/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @Data.nodes('/OrderContact/Contact/ListOfContactNumber') AS XT(XC)
```

You should get the desired output:

[image]

The `.nodes()` method call returns a XML fragment representing the `<ListOfContactNumber>` node. You need to reach into that XML fragment, and extract each `<ContactNumber>` child node - based on what value they have in `ContactNumberTypeCoded` - and then show the `<ContactNumberValue>` value as the desired output.